# Simple bank class in ruby breaking

Tags: ruby, instance-variables

I am creating a simple banking program but it keeps erroring at line 35 -- am I setting this up incorrectly with the instance variables and initializing them?

Why am I unable to access the @balance instance variable?

```
class Person
    attr_accessor :name, :initAmount

    def initialize(name, initAmount = 0)
        @name = name
        @initAmount = initAmount
        puts "Hi, #{name}.  You have $#{initAmount} on hand!"
    end
end

class Bank

    def initialize(bank_name, balance = 0, deposit = 0)
        @bankName = bank_name
        @balance = balance
        @deposit = deposit
        puts "#{bank_name} bank was just created."
    end


    def open_account(name)
        @balance = @initAmount
        puts "#{@name}, thanks for opening an account at #{@bankName}!" 
    end

    def withdrawal(name, amount)
        if amount > 0
            @balance -= amount
            puts "#{name} withdrew $#{amount} from #{@bankName}.  #{name} has #{@balance}.  #{name}'s account has #{@balance}."
        end
    end

    def deposit(name, amount)
        if amount > 0 
            @balance += amount
            puts "#{name} deposited $#{amount} to #{@bankName}. #{name} has #{@balance}. #{name}'s account has #{@balance}."
        end
    end

    def transfer(name, bankName, amount)
        if @name = name
           @balance -= amount
           puts "#{name} have transfered $#{amount} from #{@bankName} account to #{@bankName}.  Your new balance is $#{@balance}."
        else
            puts "Wrong username"
        end
    end
end

chase = Bank.new("JP Morgan Chase")
wells_fargo = Bank.new("Wells Fargo")
me = Person.new("Tom", 500)
friend1 = Person.new("hon", 1000)
chase.open_account(me)
chase.open_account(friend1)
wells_fargo.open_account(me)
wells_fargo.open_account(friend1)
chase.deposit(me, 200)
chase.deposit(friend1, 300)
chase.withdraw(me, 50)
chase.transfer(me, wells_fargo, 100)
# chase.deposit(me, 5000)
# chase.withdraw(me, 5000)
# puts chase.total_cash_in_bank
# puts wells_fargo.total_cash_in_bank
```

Please help me clarify what I am doing wrong. Isn't the essence behind instance variables that you can assign them as properties to any object that is created?

Comment: In `open_account`, you are accessing variables `@initAmount` and `@name`, but have not defined them

Comment: How are we supposed to know whats on line 35?

Comment: They are defined in the Person class -- I am trying to get a person object to be associated to a bank object. So as a person I have a name and an initial amount which can be used to create a bank account and update the account. I have used attr_accessor in the Person class to all the bank class to use those properties. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

In `open_account`, you are accessing variables `@initAmount` and `@name`, but have not defined them in the same class.

To access properties of `Person`, you should use that object.

Your method expects a `Person` object, It will be better to name it properly.  For example:

```
def open_account(person)
  @balance = person.initAmount
  puts "#{person.name}, thanks for opening an account at #{@bankName}!" 
end
```